# How to convert SHA-256 Java to JavaScript( IONIC with NPM )?

Tags: javascript, java, ionic-framework, npm, sha256

I have given the below code in `JAVA`. I need to **convert** `JavaScript` like `IONIC Framework`.I tried `IONIC App` with `NPM  "crypto-js"` and `"js-sha256"`. But, I couldn't identify the solution.

```
    String generatedPassword = null;
    String **SALTKEY** = 'mysecret';
    String inputPassword = 'mypassword';
    try {

         MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
         md.update(SALTKEY.getBytes());
         byte[] bytes = md.digest(inputPassword.getBytes());

         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
          for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            sb.append(Integer.toString((bytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
          }

      generatedPassword = sb.toString();

     } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return generatedPassword;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.Finally I got a Answer :)

```
     import { sha256, sha224 } from 'js-sha256';
     import * as forge from 'node-forge';

     const SALTKEY = 'mysecret'; 
     const inputPassword = 'mypassword';
```

Method : 1 // js-sha256 - NPM

```
     var hash = sha256.create();
     hash.update(SALTKEY);
     hash.update(inputPassword);
     console.log(hash.hex());
```

Method : 2 // node-forge - NPM

```
     var md = forge.md.sha256.create();
     md.update(SALTKEY);
     md.update(inputPassword);
     console.log(md.digest().toHex());
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `crypto-js`

check This [Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/crypto-js-spbkxx?file=sha256.ts)

or

Install usin **npm** `npm i js-sha256`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-sha256

```
import { sha256, sha224 } from 'js-sha256';
```

then

```
sha256('Your Message to hash');
sha224('Your Message to hash');

var yourHash = sha256.create();
yourHash.update('Message to hash');
yourHash.hex();

var yourHash2 = sha256.update('Message to hash');
yourHash2.update('Message2 to hash');
yourHash2.array();
```

using key

```
var hash = sha256.hmac.create('key');
hash.update('Message to hash');
hash.hex();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response and valuable time. Could you please tell me "How could I include SALTKEY and PASSWORD" the above solution?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-sha256 . ()var hash = sha256.hmac.create('key');
hash.update('Message to hash');
hash.hex();